# The point light is invisible on the scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

When I add point light in my scene, it simply doesn't have any brightness and literally invisible.[image]

Also when I add a directional light it works within all my scene (maybe it somehow related to the problem described above).

[image]

Could you please tell, how can I make point light be visible? I read that I can set Render mode to "Important", but it didn't work out. Changing intensity and range also doesn't work.

Unity version - 2020.2.7f1.4104.

Comment: What have you tried? It seems that Unity is trying to tell you that "Realtime indirect bounce shadowing" doesn't work on point lights. Have you tried turning that off?

Comment: @MrDiamond  yeah, to make this message about bounce shadowing disappear I set Indirect multiplier value to zero, but still nothing happened...Someone tell that the problem may be be solved if I reinstall Unity..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. When I created my point light it always appeared behind the level textures level, so I moved the light forward and everything works fine now.